# Cual es la direfencia entre request.query_params y self.request.query_params en Python con Django

Tags: django, djangorestframework, python-requests

Estoy iniciando con djangorestframework de django-python y tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
class ProcesoViewSet(ModelPagination, viewsets.ViewSet):

    def list(self, request):
        query = request.query_params
        query1 = self.request.query_params
        log.info(query)
        log.info(query1)
```

Me gustaría saber cual es la diferencia, hice log a los dos valores este es el resultado **(es lo mismo)**

```
<QueryDict: {'page': ['1'], 'all': ['false']}>
<QueryDict: {'page': ['1'], 'all': ['false']}>
```

Pero me gustaría saber existe ventajas y desventajas de usar una o la otra. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando se solicita una página en Django, se crea un objeto [HttpRequest](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest) que contiene información sobre la solicitud, es decir, sus atributos y métodos.

En tu ejemplo, este objeto se encuentra en la instancia de la clase `ProcesoViewSet` y tienes acceso a él desde la instancia usando `self.request`.

En `def list(self, request)` existe un parámetro que se llama `request`, pero **es solo una etiqueta**. *Casualmente* se llama `request` y ***causalmente*** contiene el contenido del objeto `self.request`. Pero solo es casualidad. Su nombre podría ser `req` o `solicitud` o cualquier otro y su función sería la misma.

Ahora bien, ambos objetos *pueden tener el mismo contenido*, **pero no necesariamente *son el mismo objeto***.

Para verificar si dos objetos **tienen el mismo contenido**, usa el operador lógico `==`.

```
query == query1
```

Para verificar si dos variables **se refieren al mismo objeto**, usa el operador `is`:

```
query is query1
```